# make a UIView with added subviews into a single image?

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a view with added subviews. I would like to turn that view with many subviews into a single image or view.

How is that possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On iOS7 you can use the new `[UIView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:]` method.

To support older OS you can render any view into an UIImage with Core Graphics. I use this category on UIView for snapshots:

`UView+Snapshot.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (Snapshot)
- (UIImage *)snapshotImage;
@end
```

`UView+Snapshot.m`:

```
#import "UIView+Snapshot.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UIView (Snapshot)

- (UIImage *)snapshotImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}

@end
```

It requires QuartzCore framework, so make sure to add that to your project.

To use it import the header and:

```
UIImage *snapshot = [interestingView snapshotImage];
```

Comment: Vytis, everything makes sense here except for `UIImage *snapshot = [interestingView snapshotImage];` Xcode complains: `Use of undeclared identifier interestingView’`. Exactly how did you declare this ?

Comment: `interestingView` is the view you want to take the snapshot image of. So for example if you want to take a snapshot of a view controller's view you will have `UIImage *snapshot = [self.view snapshotImage];`
somewhere in your UIViewController code.

Answer (score 2):

***Swift 5*** , easy to call

```
extension UIView {
    var asImg: UIImage? {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible, using Core Graphics' rendering functions you render the view into a context, and then initialize an image with the contents of that context. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500915/how-to-create-an-image-from-a-uiview-uiscrollview) for a good technique.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a swift 2.x version for Vytis example

```
extension UIView {

    func snapshotImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        self.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return resultingImage
    }
}
```