# Add UILabel on UIImage to create a new UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uilabel

I am adding a UILabel over UIImageView and adding features like increase font size, change color etc. Now what i need is that after the editing is complete we are left with the UILabel with its properties like frame, color, fontsize etc.

**I need to add the `UILabel` over `UIImage` to generate a new `UIImage`.**

Kindly suggest what needs to be done. Also correct me if i'm wrong.

I require to achieve something like this as an `UIImage`

**The Black subview is the UIImage that i require to obtain**

NOTE : 
This is absolutely not a duplicate of :

[How do I add text to an image in iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906914/how-do-i-add-text-to-an-image-in-ios-swift)
as I have many attributes to take in account as the frame , its bounds , color, font size, alignment and scale etc. I can also not screenshot the view.

[image]

**Solution :**

Someone has voted it as a duplicate so I cannot post an answer separately.
This solution worked for me perfectly.

I have created an extension for using it everywhere :
import Foundation
import UIKit

```
extension UIImage {

    class func createImageWithLabelOverlay(label: UILabel,imageSize: CGSize, image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height), false, 2.0)
        let currentView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))
        let currentImage = UIImageView.init(image: image)
        currentImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height)
        currentView.addSubview(currentImage)
        currentView.addSubview(label)
        currentView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img!
    }

}
```

Usage : 
Anywhere on your ViewController where you have the size and the label to add use it as follows -

```
let newImageWithOverlay = UIImage.createImageWithLabelOverlay(label: labelToAdd, imageSize: size, image: editedImage)
```

Comment: can you add an image of what exactly do you want ?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11151286/3901620

Comment: @Priyal Please find the update with image

Comment: You can add UIImageView on a UIView and then add UILabel. Then you can take a screenshot of the parent view. Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview

Comment: @GirishM : I cannot take a screenshot as the user can edit it anytime and there are more than one images which i store in a model. So i want to get something in which I provide the Image and Label and generate a flat image from them.

Comment: @KKRocks please refer to my comment to Girish

Comment: @GirishM : I have posted the solution that worked fine for me. Kindly have a look and let me know if I missed something.